# Gradle idea plugin: java.io.File cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, gradlew

I am using

```
Gradle version: 2.6
Groovy version: 2.3.10
```

There is an error as the title when I running `gradlew idea`

Comment: Could you please provide your build.gradle content

Comment: Thanks, I have solve this problem, because Goovy caculate is changed from  1.8.9. So the configurations must as  ....+= [dependencies]

Comment: @AngleTom can you please kindly post your comment as the answer and update your Q? If not I'll post it for you because this is exactly the answer I (and I'm sure others) are looking for.

Comment: @xlm When you add the dependencies for your project. Before Goovy 1.8.9, you can do like this `dependen = ---the dependency---`. After that you have to do like this `dependen = [--- the dependency ---]`

Comment: @AngleTom sorry I'm not clear. What I meant was your comment to change it to `[dependencies]` is the answer. Can you post answers? If so please post it/mark it as correct. If not I'll post it on your behalf. I've upvoted both the Q and your comment :)

Comment: @xlm I mean that you can define an array like this `def test = new String[3]` and you can append a item like this `test += "hello"` before Goovy 1.8.9.

Comment: @xlm but after 1.8.9, you can't add item like this. you have to add item like this `test += ["hello"]`

Answer (score 3):

On behalf of [Angle Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5093293/angle-tom):

The cast error occurs when using a `build.gradle` configured against a older version of Groovy (used by Gradle).

In this case, the issue with Gradle Idea plugin likely arises from the following example from the [pre-2.0 Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/1.12/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html#org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule:scopes) which uses Groovy 1.8:

```
idea {
  module {
    scopes.PROVIDED.plus += configurations.provided
  }
}
```

From Gradle 2.0, Groovy was updated from 1.8 to 2.3.2 as mentioned in the [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/2.0/release-notes#updated-to-groovy-2.3.2). The major bump to the Groovy version meant that the syntax for appending to lists changed. Thus the Gradle docs were [updated](https://docs.gradle.org/2.0/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html#org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule:scopes) to reflect this:

```
idea {
  module {
    scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [ configurations.provided ]
  }
}
```